# how to fill the computer object description in windows AD from Linux CLI

Tags: linux, windows, domain

I am trying to join a Linux machine to a domain while also adding some description to the object so when i look for it later i can get some more info on it.
ive tried adcli, realmd, net ads and such but non of them seem to have the option to add the description to the active directory description field.
is it possible to do so from some linux tool?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day Active Directory is just a fancy over engineered LDAP server.  You should be able to change whatever attributes you'd like on any object using the OpenLDAP tools.  The exact command will depend on your AD configuration and schema.